# Using NGINX to kick off a process when a URL is requested?

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Assuming the process isn't running to begin with; is it possible to kick off a process when a URL is visited by a browser for the first time, and then make sure that the browser is forwarded to the same requested URL (which now has a running process...)?

The reason I ask is that I have a server-side wiki written in node.js that I would like to run many instances of, but it is running on a server with very limited resources (a Raspberry pi), and I'm afraid if I kick off all the wiki processses at once I'll run out of memory for them to run in.

I'm also planning on eventually have a cron job that checks to see if they have been used and shut them down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back in the day, most web servers would support CGI, which basically just sends the request data to a script and takes the response and sends it back to the client.  Nginx does not support CGI directly, but it does support FastCGI and [someone has made some code to do what you want](http://wiki.nginx.org/SimpleCGI), effectively wrapping CGI with FastCGI.

However, I think you're asking the wrong question.  Your actual application is running in Node.js.  Why would you like to run many instances of it?  Starting them all at once or staggered will not likely make any difference in your memory usage.  They are going to take memory when running, no matter when you started them.  Consider that you probably only need one of these instances.

Comment: Well, I have a file system of thumbdrive-based wiki's that I keep as a reference for programming languages, apis and other topics etc...Each of these reside in their own HTML file, but they frequently refer to one another via links.  This allows me to keep the topics separate, but allows me to but links to references where two apis might intersect or be used together; so I can put the actual text of a tutorial or instructions in the one apis wiki and put a link to the same information in the other.

Comment: @leeand00 What does that have anything to do with your number of application instances?  In fact, what does that have to with Node.js?  It sounds to me like all you need is a proper Nginx config.

Comment: This way I don't repeat myself but I can still find the information when I look for it in a wiki about either api or topic.  But if I shove all the information into a single wiki, it'll be a big mess.  I don't need all of them running at the same time, I just need the ones running that I'm looking at.  I might run 3 wiki apps at once at the most.

Comment: Sorry see my above comments..and yes you're right it has nothing to do with node.js

Comment: What application are you using to run this wiki?  Is this something you wrote or found somewhere?  You're saying that each wiki needs its own application server?  From what you said in your comment, it sounds like you're just serving static HTML.

Comment: It's tiddlywiki, there is a self modifying .html file version and a serverside version in node.js

Comment: Well, CGI mode won't help you then anyway since I doubt TiddlyWiki is going to like being CGI.  You're going to have to write your own daemon that launches the process on request, waits for it to start, and then proxies request data to it and response data from it.

Comment: Why do you doubt it will like being CGI?

Comment: @leeand00 Node.js applications don't typically speak CGI... they use HTTP instead.